# Erro generate app in macOS

Tags: react-native

I'm with this message after create my app using this command: react-native init...

> npm WARN react-native@0.56.0 requires a peer of react@16.4.1 but none was installed.
>   You are currently running Node v6.10.3 but React Native requires >=8. Please use a supported version of Node.
>   See https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
>   /Users/gustavo/React-native/projetos/SmartPark/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/server/checkNodeVersion.js:43

And when i try by this command: create-react-native-app... in the end of the creation this message is showen

> npm ERR! cb() never called!
>   Failed to install

What is this?
The version of react-native-cli is 2.0.1

Comment: Did you read the error? Your Node version is outdated.

Comment: Yes! But I thought that could be react instalation, but i will update node. Let's see if  it is the only problem.

Comment: Thank you @Li357, just it works